# How to use Ionic 3 with MS Visual Studio Community 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ionic3

I've been using Ionic 2 with MS Visual Studio Community 2017 for quite some time now.
In the Visual Studio Market the plugin Ionic 2 Templates for VS can be downloaded and used.

It is as simple as clicking:

> New Project > TypeScript > Mobile Apps > Ionic 2 - Blank

However I can not find a template for Ionic 3. *( seems not released yet)*

Any idea how to manually add Ionic 3 to Visual Studio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Future readers of this answer need to understand that the versions referenced below are the latest versions of the packages at the time of this posting.  That means, newer versions may be available at the time of reading.

1. Upgrade your Ionic CLI. At the time of this post, the latest version is 3.9.1.

> npm install -g ionic

2. Upgrade your NPM Ionic package dependencies.
   Most likely you'll need 4.x versions of Angular, and the associated Angular npm dependencies (i.e. CORE, COMPILER, FORMS, HTTP, etc). Most likely you'll need 3.x versions of Ionic-Angular, and 4.x versions of Ionic native packages.

The best way to do this, in my mind, is to use the latest version of the Ionic CLI to create a brand new temporary Ionic application. And then examine the NPM packages listed in the package.json file, and manually update your real application's package.json to match.  Be cautious and methodical.

For your convienance, I've attached a default package.json dependencies that's created with a brand new Ionic 3 application.

```
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/core": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/forms": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/http": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.5",
        "@ionic-native/core": "4.1.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.1.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.1.0",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
        "ionic-angular": "3.6.0",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "rxjs": "5.4.3",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.16"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.4",
        "typescript": "2.3.4"
      },
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm just getting started so this might be not quite right, but I did the following:

- Ensure you have the Cordova workload installed through VS2017 installer.
- Create a new project using VS2017 and the Ionic 2 template
- Install Ionic latest if you haven't, via the command line:

  - `npm install -g ionic@latest`
- Create a new Ionic 3 app, via the command line. Use `sidemenu` or `tabs` or `blank` depending on what template you want to use. I see there's a ton more in https://market.ionic.io/starters/ which you can probably use somehow.

  - `ionic start YourNewAppName sidemenu`
- Copy files from your Ionic 2 project folder into your Ionic 3 project folder:

  - `taco.json`
  - `XXXX.jsproj` (don't rename just yet)
  - `XXXX.sln` (don't rename just yet)
- Launch the XXXX.sln in VS2017

  - VS prompted me to upgrade project file, OK.
  - VS prompted me to set version of typescript, OK.

Now the .sln file works for editing & running the Ionic 3 project

Comment: I tried using the npm but it was not recognized so i Installed Node JS. Now same error is given when using ionic. google suggested installing cordova. how come am i able to use ionic without those being installed inside visyal studio 2017?

Comment: Yeah you need Cordova installed through VS2017 to make it all work within VS.

Comment: I tried this and the sln works (more or less). But when building for android the ionic:build isn't started and after the apk was build (I was able to start ionic:build via NPM Task Runner) I get an error that no apk was found to publish to device. But the apk was created and can be found in the outputs\apk\debug folder. Any help/advice?